# A sequence has no limit point in unit disk, then $D_1 \setminus \{a_n\}$ is open.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I need to show the if $\{a_n\} \subset \Bbb{C}$ is a sequence with no limit point in the unit disk, show unit disk minus $\{a_n\}$ is open,

So I want to go about it by contradiction. So if $D_1 \setminus \{a_n\}$ is not open, then it contains a boundary point. Say some $z_0$ such that $B_\epsilon(z_0)$ contains points both inside and outside of $D_1 \setminus \{a_n\}$. Any hints greatly appreciated.

Comment: To prove that $D_{1} \setminus \{ a_{n} \mid n \in \omega \}$ is open, consider a point $x$ in $D_{1} \setminus \{ a_{n} \mid n \in \omega \}$. You must find an open ball around $x$ which lies in $D_{1} \setminus \{ a_{n} \mid n \in \omega \}$. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that no such ball exists. Then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the sequence $(a_n)\subset \mathbb{C} $ has no limit point in $D_1=D(0, 1) $

Let $A=\{x_n:n\in\Bbb{N}\}$

Claim : $D_1\setminus A$ is open.

Proof: Assume the contrary that $D_1\setminus A$ is not open.

Then $\exists x_0\in D_1\setminus A$ such that $\forall r>0, D(x_0, r) \not\subset D_1\setminus A $

Hence $\forall n\in\Bbb{N} ,\exists (x_n) \subset A$ such that $x_n\in D(x_0, \frac{1}{n}) $.

Since $(x_n)\subset A$ and $(x_n)\to x_0\in D_1$ implies $x_0\in D_1$ is a limit point of $A$.

**Contradiction.**

Comment: does this work if we assume our sequence in contained in the unit disk?

Comment: Yes. This proof is stable under any choice of sequences.